# Problem about intermediate fields in the extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $E,K$ be intermediate fields in the extension $L/F$

(a) If $[EK:F]$ is finite, then

$$[EK:F] \leq [E:F][K:F] $$

(b) If  $E$ and $K$ are algebraic over $F$, then so is $EK$

For (a), I try two ways:

(1) I try to prove that $[EK:K]\leq [E:F]$ and $[EK:E]\leq [K:F]$.

(2) $x_1,\dotsc,x_m$ are base of $E/F$, $y_1,\dotsc,y_n$ are base of $K/F$, but how to prove that $\{x_iy_j\}$ span  $EK$?

Comment: *To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are*. That way, people won't tell you stuff you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

A. Pick bases $S$ (resp. $T$) for $E/F$ (resp. $K/F$(. Show that the products $st,s\in S, t\in T$ span all of $EK$.

B. Review what you know about products and sums of two algebraic elements.

---

Extending... In both parts, A and B, you know that $E$ and $K$ are algebraic. This implies that the compositum is
$$
EK=\{\sum_{i=1}^n e_ik_i\mid n\in\mathbb{N};  e_i\in E, k_i\in K\ \text{for all $i$}\},
$$
i.e. the elements of the compositum are finite sums of products of elements of $E$ and $K$.

For part A you can pick bases $S=\{s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_m\}$ and $T=\{t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n\}$ as in the hint. Take a sum $\sum_i e_ik_i$ as above. For all $i$, you can write $e_i=\sum_j a_{ij}s_j$ and $k_i=\sum_\ell b_{i\ell}t_\ell$ with all the coefficients $a_{ij},b_{i\ell}\in F$. Plugging these in you see that
$$
\sum_ie_ik_i=\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{\ell=1}^n\left(\sum_{p,q}a_{pj}b_{q\ell}\right)s_jt_\ell.
$$
So all the elements of $EK$ can be written as $F$-linear combinations of the elements $s_jt_\ell$. Therefore the elements $s_jt_\ell$ span $EK$. There are
$mn=[E:F][K:F]$ of them.

In part B you are supposed to recall results saying that if all the elements $e_i$ and $k_i$ are algebraic over $F$, then so are the products $e_ik_i$. And also that the sum
$$
e_1k_1+e_2k_2+e_3k_3+\cdots+e_nk_n
$$
is algebraic as a sum of algebraic elements.

Comment: would you say it more clearly? thanks

Comment: Thanks!   denote by $EK$ the smallest subfield of $L$ containing both $E$ and $K$.  How to prove that the elements of the compositum are finite sums of products of elements of $E$ and $K$? the rest is trivial

Comment: The set of finite sums of the prescribed form is clearly closed under addition and multiplication. The inverses are there, iff the elements are algebraic over $F$. This is because, if the space spanned by these sums has dimension $N$, then for all such sums $\alpha$, the powers $\alpha^i,i=0,1,\ldots,N,$ are linearly dependent over $F$. Thus $\alpha$ is also algebraic, and we can find an inverse using its minimal polynomial.